# C# : How to check a DataRow against a String

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I current have a connection open which just queries through with a dependency of user input. My Objects are correct and I have set-up the Instances related to the Objects and it is all working fine.

I now need to match if the user input is the same as the stored Database data however, it does not seem to be working; i am getting no errors though.

After doing a bit of my own debugging and researching, I tried to convert my DataRow to a String using `ToString();` but still no luck.

Could anyone possible take a look into this section of code and possibly help me try to figure this out? Many thanks.

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
query = new MySqlDataAdapter(SQL, conn);
query.Fill(ds, "AllData");
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt = ds.Tables["AllData"];
DataRow[] r = dt.Select();
int i = 0;
while (i != r.Length)
    {
     string toTest = r[i]["BusinessID"].ToString();
     if(toTest == sinput)
    {
```

Note: `sinput` is the Users input and `r[i]["BusinessID"]` contains the data in the database which I am trying to match against the input string.

Edit: I have not passed anything into the `dt.Select()` for security purposes as I do not want direct user input into a query.

Comment: you could consider doing `dt[i]["businessID].ToString();` instead of the data row

Comment: That I have tried also. I did a simple `Reponse.Write(r[i]["BusinessID"]);` and it does hold the correct Data, just for some reason, I cannot match strings against its held data.

Comment: is `sinput` holding the right value too? your snippet doesnt show the assignment

Comment: Put a breakpoint before your if statement and inspect the values for `toTest` and `sinput`, what you've described says they don't match. Beware that two strings that look the same might not match if they use different encoding. You could try using `string.Equals(str1, str2, comparison);` instead of `==` as you can specify the comparison type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please find the code:Instead of data from database i have hard code the value.
Hope,it will help you.

```
        string Name = "Test1";
        int Id = 1;
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("Id",typeof(int));
        dt.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
        dt.Rows.Add(1,"Test");
        dt.Rows.Add(1, "Test1");
        DataRow[] r = dt.Select();
        int i = 0; //Not Required.
        while (r.Length>0)
        {
            string toTest = r[i]["Name"].ToString();
            int toTest1 =Convert.ToInt32(r[i]["Id"]);
            if (toTest == Name)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(toTest);
            }
            if (toTest1 == Id)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(toTest1);
            }
        }
```

Comment: I appreciate that but the BusinessID is actually things like AR44 (String). So this won't work. I have taken it into liberation and will study your method. Thank-you!

Comment: You mean to say you have businessId as :pattern of varchar (int + character).

Comment: Yes, that is the pattern. my method in the question does work, I was outputting the result after the match in the wrong place and therefore not noticing that it was actually working: silly me.